# Initializer element is not a compile-time constant but compiler doesn't throw error

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, bare-metal

I'm studying embedded systems and implementing a `startup.c` file from scratch. Upon creating the interrupt vector table, I get the following error on my editor (I'm using `clangd` as my LSP):

[image]

startup.c:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define SRAM_START 0x20000000U                
#define SRAM_SIZE (128U * 1024U)              
#define SRAM_END ((SRAM_START) + (SRAM_SIZE)) 
#define STACK_START SRAM_END 

int main(void);
void reset_handler(void);
/* more stuff */

uint32_t vectors[] __attribute__((section(".isr_vectors"))) = {
    STACK_START,
    (uint32_t)reset_handler,
    /* more stuff */
}

void reset_handler(void){
    /* .data, .text and .bss */
    main();
}
```

Why is it that gcc allows this to compile?

Comment: Re “Why is it that gcc allows this to compile?”: [GCC 13.2 for x86_64 does not allow this to compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/eG7s79W8M) Edit the question to state the version of GCC you are using and the switches you use to compile. I suspect that GCC may compile the code when the cast matches the pointer width. Essentially, it recognizes the cast as a null operation and treats it as an address constant (C 2018 6.6 9), which will be filled in by the linker. If the cast does not match, the value cannot be filled in by the compiler or the linker, so there would be an error.

Comment: With Clang used for error detection in the editor, it may be that Clang is not configured for the target you are compiling. Incidentally, you might want to switch to using `uintptr_t` instead of `uint32_t`, as that better expresses the fact the array will be holding addresses as integers.

Comment: Note C 2018 6.6 10: “An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions.”

Comment: The `vectors` array should probably have members of type `void (*)(void)`.

Comment: Ignoring the pointer/integer mismatch, what element do you think is not a compile-time constant?

Comment: The IDE/code editor language parser may not be applying the same rules or have the same target specific information the build tool-chain has.  If it builds, ignore it - treat such diagnostics has a helpful guide, not as absolute truth.  It works better where the toolchain and IDE are tightly couples such as Visual Studio and Visual C++, or ARM Compiler and Keil uVision,  but with looser integrations such as VSCode, gcc and clang or whatever, YMMV.  For a start, the IDE is clearly assuming a 64-bit target, while the code is evidently for a 32-bit target.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, an address constant cast to integer type does not satisfy the language spec's definition of a constant expression, and especially not its definition of "integer constant expression".  But that does not mean that implementations cannot accept it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that gcc allows this to compile?

C implementations are not required to *reject* any particular code.  They are required to *emit a diagnostic message* describing each constraint violation, but even for those, they can otherwise do whatever they want.  Literally whatever: such code has no defined behavior as far as the standard is concerned.  Many implementations implement extensions that involve accepting code that violates language constraints.

With that said, your IDE's message is misleading.  The expression in question indeed does not satisfy the definition of an "integer constant expression", nor of any other type of constant expression that the spec explicitly permits to appear in an initializer for an object with static or thread storage duration.  But without the cast it would be an *address constant*, which is allowed in initializers, and it's plausible that the cast could be evaluated at translation time, especially when building for a 32-bit architecture.

In that light, then, consider also that the spec explicitly allows implementations to accept other forms of constant expressions.

I can't say why your particular gcc accepts the code, but **overall, nothing requires C implementations to reject it, and for some implementations, it would be entirely natural to accept it.**

Comment: Re “it's plausible that the cast could be evaluated at compile time, especially when compiling for a 32-bit architecture”: The compiler cannot evaluate the cast to a value because it does not know the address of `reset_handler`. Accepting the cast as an address constant requires semantic analysis that the cast has no effect in the C implementation (produces an integer with the same byte representation as the address operand), which is then satisfied by emitting relocation information for the linker, not a numeric value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, you explain well why the spec does not include such expressions in the definition of integer constant expressions, but as you yourself observed in a different comment, that does not mean that any particular implementation cannot accept them as constant expressions.  The OP claims that their implementation *does* accept the code presented.  What, then, is the point you are trying to make?

Comment: The point is “it’s plausible that the cast could be evaluated at compile time” is an incorrect explanation of why the compiler accepts the code. The cast cannot be evaluated at compile time, because the compiler does not know the address of `reset_handler`. And a person who believed this incorrect explanation would be misled about what expressions the compiler accepts, because, if the compiler could evaluate `(uint32_t) reset_handler`, then it would know its bits, so it would know its low bits, so it could also evaluate `(uint16_t) reset_handler`…

Comment: … However, while GCC will accept the former while compiling for a target with 32-bit addresses, it will not accept the latter. That is because the correct explanation is it is not able to evaluate the cast but does have a code for a relocation entry it can put into the object file to tell the linker to complete the 32-bit address later, but it cannot do the same thing for a 16-bit portion of the address. (Actually might on some architectures, but that is another matter.) It is false the compiler can evaluate the cast, and it is true it can treat the cast to `uint32_t` as a no-op.

Comment: So, @EricPostpischil, you are complaining that I said "compiler" instead of "toolchain" or "implementation"?  Very well.  I accept that criticism, but I think it will be lost on most of the audience.  I have tweaked the language of this answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it that gcc allows this to compile?

He doesn't. Just make the vectors an array of function pointers.

```
typedef void (*const pHandler)(void);
__attribute__((section(".isr_vectors"), used)) 
pHandler vectors[] = {
    (pHandler)STACK_START,
    reset_handler,
};
```

> why changing the type of the elements solves the issue regarding the functions not being const initializers? – Gerhardh

The problem with OP code is the conversion from a function pointer `&reset_handler` to a `uint32_t` value at `(uint32_t)reset_handler,`. Below, I present a smaller code example highlighting the problem:

```
#include <stdint.h>
void reset_handler(void);
uint32_t c = reset_handler; // error - not able to compute reset_handler as uint32_t at compile time
```

By changing the type of the array, the conversion is no longer needed, so it can be removed. By removing the code causing the error, the issue is solved.

Comment: Do you have any explanation why changing the type of the elements solves the issue regarding the functions not being const initializers?

Comment: Hi @Gerhardh I do not know what exactly are you asking about. Changing type to what type exactly of which elements exactly solves what issue exactly? `(uint32_t)reset_handler,`  is not a constant expression, but I do not think it's relevant, changing it's type does not "solve" it (does it?). Are you asking about `(pHandler)STACK_START,`? The `(pHandler)` is to silence compiler warning about conversion, not to solve an issue.

Comment: Strange reply. You changed the elements of array `vectors` from `uint32_t` to `pHandler`. The question is about error message "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant".

Comment: So you are asking about why changing the type of the _array_ elements solves the issue? Because then you do not have to convert a function pointer to uint32_t. It's hard to explain why something does not happen. In the original code, conversion of a function pointer to uint32_t is not a compile-time constant. This code solves it by not doing the conversion.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Changing the type is one way of solving the issue because casting a function address to an integer type is not one of the forms of constant the C standard requires be supported but casting an integer to a pointer type is one of the forms required, in C 2018 6.6 9: “An *address constant* is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator; it shall be created explicitly using the unary `&` operator **or an integer constant cast to pointer type**…”

Comment: Nonetheless, this post does not answer the question OP asked, which is why GCC accepts `(uint32_t) reset_handler`.

Comment: @KamilCuk so the cast makes the expression being not compile-time-constant? Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @EricPostpischil another day, another thing to learn. Thank you for the explanation.